# Solid-state replacement for a mechanical switch for a DC motor

Tags: dc-motor, solid-state-relay

I have a battery-powered circular saw. The design looks very simple, basically a 18-20V lithium battery pack connected through a mechanical switch to a "895" brushed DC motor. The switch contacts are failing, and I haven't been able to locate a suitable replacement. The original switch is marked as "25A DC 24V 5E4", but the fact that it's failing seems to indicate that it's not well suited for this application (here is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=il80xWI9EoI&t=7m04s) showing the exact same problem).

I'm thinking of making a solid-state replacement - something like a big FET (or two - in the OFF state, the switch shorts the motor to stop it quickly) driven by a low-spec (perhaps even the original, worn-out) mechanical switch.

1. Does this make sense?
2. How can I estimate the voltage & current requirements for the FET
3. What kind of filtering, or other circuitry would I need?

Comment: Yes, this is possible, but I don't like the idea, that you lose a finger while using my schematic. A FET failure is also very dangerous here. The safety aspects of the switch must not be ignored.